# How do I use the child element of 'this' as a selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that calls when the user `mouseover` a certain div. The function shows a different div, but the issue is that it shows all of the divs with that class.

Here's the JS:

```
$('.edit-image').mouseover(
  function(e){
  $('.edit-image-link').show();
});
```

What I want it to do is only show the `.edit-image-link` div if it's a child of the element that the user has their mouse over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to fetch only the descendant elements of an element based on a selector.

```
$('.edit-image').mouseover(function (e) {
    $(this).find('.edit-image-link').show();
});
```

or you can pass a context to jQuery for searching a selector

```
$('.edit-image').mouseover(function (e) {
    $('.edit-image-link', this).show();
});
```

*Note: Inside a jQuery callback method like event handlers, this will refer the to current dom element*

<sub>I personally prefer the first method</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.edit-image').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find('.edit-image-link').show();
});
```

References

[this keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.